# RevMob giving error on CLLocation manager

Tags: ios8, cocos2d-x, revmob

I am simply adding the revmob nothing. fancy
I get this error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_kCLLocationAccuracyBest", referenced from:
>         -[RevMobDeviceInfo getUserLocation] in RevMobAds(RevMobDeviceInfo.o)   "_kCLDistanceFilterNone", referenced
>   from:
>         -[RevMobDeviceInfo getUserLocation] in RevMobAds(RevMobDeviceInfo.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in RevMobAds(RevMobDeviceInfo.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I checked on rebmov documentation and forum. it seem they have removed the method. 
https://forum.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/topic/108/ios-sdk-missing-setuserlocation-on-revmobads-session

I followed their guideline here 
http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html#session

Does anyone know how to bypass this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add CoreLocation.framework in xCode

make sure all these frameworks are added in xCode

```
SystemConfiguration.framework, 
StoreKit.framework
MediaPlayer.framework 
CoreLocation.framework
AdSupport.framework
```

Comment: Thanks man, I totally miss out on Corelocation Framework. Let me try this again. If that solves the issue. I will accept your answer.